Writing a generic makefile for C projects
Directory Structure:
.
├── check.sh
├── GNUmakefile
├── Makefile
└── src


Makefile has these contents:
# Dummy Makefile to indicate that GNU Make should be used.

.POSIX:
all x:
    @echo "You need GNU Make to build x" 1>&2; false

When run on Solaris, a BSD system, or any other system that doesn't come with GNU make as the default make, this results in a nice error message. On Linux, and others that come with GNU make as the default, this file is ignored because GNU make looks for "GNUMakefile" first.

The src directory is empty because I haven't actually written any code yet. "check.sh" is a shell script that checks whether the program has been installed at $(PREFIX)/bin/. If it is not, it prints a message showing how to add $(PREFIX)/bin/ to the PATH variable, and then offers to add it automatically. (There's no test directory or test target because there are none yet. I will add that later.)

It is generic in the sense that I only have to change the value of target for other projects, because the directory structure remains the same. It should work at least on Windows (MINGW64 and CYGWIN), Linux, Oracle Solaris, OmniOS, OpenBSD, NetBSD, FreeBSD, and Mac OS X. (Assuming proper tools like gcc/clang, valgrind, lubsan et cetera are installed).


Makefile:
ifeq '$(PREFIX)' ''
    ifeq ($(shell id -u), 0)
        PREFIX   := /usr/local
    else
        PREFIX   := $(HOME)/.local
    endif
endif

MKDIR            := mkdir
INSTALL          := install -Dpm 755
RM               := rm
VALGRIND         := valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes

CC               := $(CC)
CFLAGS           := $(CFLAGS)
CFLAGS           += -std=c2x
CFLAGS           += -I..

COMPILE.C        = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) 

COMPILER_VERSION := $(shell $(CC) --version)

ifneq '$(findstring debug,$(MAKECMDGOALS))' ''
    CFLAGS += -g3
    CFLAGS += -ggdb

    CFLAGS += -no-pie

    CFLAGS += -fno-builtin
    CFLAGS += -fno-common
    CFLAGS += -fno-omit-frame-pointer

    CFLAGS += -Wall
    CFLAGS += -Wextra
    CFLAGS += -Warray-bounds

    CFLAGS += -Wconversion
    CFLAGS += -Wformat-signedness
    CFLAGS += -Wno-parentheses
    CFLAGS += -Wpedantic
    CFLAGS += -pedantic-errors
    CFLAGS += -Wstrict-prototypes
    CFLAGS += -Wwrite-strings
    CFLAGS += -Wno-missing-braces
    CFLAGS += -Wno-missing-field-initializers

    CFLAGS += -fsanitize=address
    CFLAGS += -fsanitize=undefined
    CFLAGS += -fsanitize=bounds-strict
    CFLAGS += -fsanitize=leak
    CFLAGS += -fsanitize=null
    CFLAGS += -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow
    CFLAGS += -fsanitize=bool
    CFLAGS += -fsanitize=pointer-overflow
    CFLAGS += -fsanitize-address-use-after-scope

    ifneq '$(findstring clang,$(COMPILER_VERSION))' ''
        CFLAGS += -fsanitize=function
        CFLAGS += -fsanitize=implicit-unsigned-integer-truncation
        CFLAGS += -fsanitize=implicit-signed-integer-truncation
        CFLAGS += -fsanitize=implicit-integer-sign-change
        CFLAGS += -Wreserved-identifier
        CFLAGS += -Xanalyzer
    else ifneq '$(findstring gcc,$(COMPILER_VERSION))' ''
        CFLAGS += -Wformat-signedness
        CFLAGS += -Wsuggest-attribute=pure
        CFLAGS += -Wsuggest-attribute=const
        CFLAGS += -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn
        CFLAGS += -Wsuggest-attribute=cold
        CFLAGS += -Wsuggest-attribute=malloc
        CFLAGS += -Wsuggest-attribute=format
        CFLAGS += -fanalyzer
    endif
else ifneq '$(findstring release,$(MAKECMDGOALS))' ''
    ifneq '$(findstring gcc,$(COMPILER_VERSION))' ''
        ifeq '$(firstword $(sort $(shell $(CC) -dumpversion) 14))' '14'
            CFLAGS += -fhardened
        else
            CFLAGS += -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
            CFLAGS += -fPIE
        endif
    endif

    CFLAGS += -pedantic
    CFLAGS += -O3
    CFLAGS += -march=native
    CFLAGS += -s
endif

src-dir   := src
srcs      := $(wildcard $(src-dir)/*.c)
obj-dir   := obj
objs      := $(patsubst $(src-dir)/%.c,$(obj-dir)/%.o,$(srcs))
deps      := $(objs:.o=.d)

target    := kilo

.PHONY: release debug 

release debug: $(target)
    
$(target): $(objs) | $(obj-dir) 
    $(COMPILE.C) -o $@ $^

$(obj-dir)/%.o: CFLAGS += -MMD -c
$(obj-dir)/%.o: $(src-dir)/%.c | $(obj-dir)
    $(COMPILE.C) -o $@ $<

$(obj-dir):
    $(MKDIR) $(obj-dir)

ifneq '$(MAKECMDGOALS)' 'clean'
    -include $(deps)
endif

.PHONY: valgrind
valgrind: clean $(target)
    $(VALGRIND) ./$(target)

.PHONY: fclean
fclean:
    $(RM) $(target)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) -rf $(obj-dir) $(target) 

.PHONY: install
install: release
    $(INSTALL) $(target) $(PREFIX)/bin
    @./check.sh $(PREFIX)/bin $(target)

.PHONY: uninstall
uninstall:
    $(RM) -f $(PREFIX)/bin/$(target)

.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

Review Request:
Redundancies, duplication, simplifications. Anything. Everything.

CC := $(CC) is a null op.

@CrisLuengo Does it not change it from a recursively expanded variable to a simply expanded variable?

Does that matter? $(CC) will still produce the same value it did before that statement. Was CC even defined in terms of other variables?

Not for $(CC) really. Just saw it being suggested on some StackOverflow answers.

This looks wrong:

$(target): $(objs) | $(obj-dir) 
    $(COMPILE.C) -o $@ $^


Make predefines $(LINK.c) for this command.

Only now did I discover $(COMPILE.c) and $(LINK.c), thanks! Do you think there would be a problem due to keeping the object files of both the debug and release build in the same directory?

That can be a problem, as they share the same names and we can end up linking a mismatching set of objects.  I guess it depends whether their public interfaces depend on NDEBUG etc. (when we add that to CFLAGS release builds).  Instead of rewriting %.o: %c rules, I find it better to start a sub-make in the output directory (something like +$(MAKE) $(builddir) -f ../Makefile $@ VPATH=$(PWD)).  Then you can build as many configurations as you want, from a single source directory which doesn't need to be writeable by the user doing the build.

Sorry for the very short review - I have a lot going on until late July.  I hope you get a more thorough answer as well!

That's completely alright. Have a good month!
